# Problema con for each pasandole un array(procedente de una consulta select)

Tags: php, sql

Mi problema es que al hacer un `select` a una tabla, la cual guarda fotos:

```
CREATE TABLE FOTOS_I (

  OID_FI INTEGER,
  URL VARCHAR2(800),
  OID_I INTEGER,

  PRIMARY KEY (OID_FI),

  FOREIGN KEY (OID_I) REFERENCES INMUEBLES

);
```

El `OID_I` es una foreign key que esta relaciona con la `OID` de la tabla `INMUEBLE`. En nuestro caso, tenemos varias fotos para cada inmueble. Tenemos un código PHP que nos muestra las fotos.

La primera haría la consulta a la tabla con el `OID_I` del inmueble y queremos que el `foreach` vaya recorriendo cada URL de ese inmueble. Nuestro problema es que nos muestra solo una foto de todas las que tenemos en la base de datos.

```
    function consultarFotosInmueble($conexion, $id_InmuebleJ){
       try {
        $consulta = "SELECT URL_INMU FROM FOTOS_I WHERE OID_I=:oidInmu";
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $stmt->bindParam(':oidInmu', $id_InmuebleJ);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //PDO::FETHC_ASSOC PARA ASOCIAR 
     LOS ELEMENTOS CON EL NOMBRE QUE TIENEN EN BD
      } catch (PDOexception $e) {
        $_SESSION["excepcion"] = "Error al obtener el cliente";
        header("location: excepcion.php");
      }
    }
   <?php


    $conexion = crearConexionBD();

    $fotosInmue = consultarFotosInmueble($conexion, $id_inmuebleJ);

    cerrarConexionBD($conexion);


        foreach($fotosInmue as $fotoInmue){



     ?>
      <br>
      <img src="<?php echo ($fotoInmue)?>"/>
     <?php
       }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

La razón por la que solo retorna una foto es porque `fetch()` solo lee un registro.  Necesitas usar `fetchAll();` así:

```
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Carlos!! Ya nos funciona como queriamos